# Put two conditions in an input

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I  run this program

```
emails=[]
a=(0)
while a==(0):
    user_email= input("Please write email")
    if "@" in user_email:
        if ".edu"in user_email:
            print("Adding email to list")
            emails.append(user_email)
            print(emails)
        else:
            a=(0)
       a=(0)
   else:
    print("Error:Email does not meet requirements")
       a=(0)
```

And I type an input that meets only one of the requirements, it only displays the error message in one scenario. How could I make the error message show up in both  cases where the requirements are not met since I cant write two conditions in the "if" statement.

Comment: Why can't you use two conditions in your if statement?

Comment: All `a=(0)` (inside the `while` loop) with associated `else` are unnecessary. You never change the value of `a`.

Comment: Printing a growing list of e-mails (`print(emails)`) inside an infinite loop is likely a bad idea.

Comment: Is there an exit condition out of this loop?

Answer (score 1):

Use `and` keywords, print error message for all other scenarios.

```
if '@' in user_email and '.edu' in user_email:
    pass
else:
    print('error')
```

Or

```
if all(keyword in user_email for keyword in ['@', '.edu']):
    pass
else:
    print('error')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
emails=[]
while True:
    user_email= input("Please write email: ")
    if user_email.count("@") == 1 and user_email.count(".edu") == 1:
            print("Adding email to list")
            emails.append(user_email)
            print(emails)
    else:
        print("Error:Email does not meet requirements")
```

Or using regular expression:

```
import re
emails=[]
while True:
    user_email= input("Please write email: ")
    email_pt = re.compile("^[\w.]+@[\w.]+\.edu$")
    if email_pt.search(user_email):
        print("Adding email to list")
        emails.append(user_email)
        print(emails)
    else:
        print("Error:Email does not meet requirements")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function for you to use that can replace your nested if statements:

```
#A nice function that returns true if @ and .edu are in the mail
def matches(user_email):

    boolean = True

    if '@' not in user_email:
        boolean = False

    if '.edu' not in user_email:
        boolean = False

    return boolean


#Your new code
emails=[]
a=(0)
while a==(0):
    user_email= str(input("Please write email: "))

    #New function in use
    if matches(user_email):
        print("Adding email to list")
        emails.append(user_email)
        print(emails)
    else:
        print("Error:Email does not meet requirements")
```

Hope this helps! :D